# Sikuli - Configuration in scripts 1920x1080

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

Why is it necessary to provide a configutaion in sikuli scripts like 1920x1080?
And is it mandatory to provide 1920x1080 configutaion only ?
Can we provide some other configuration for new scripts in our existing code where some scripts are designed using 1920x1080 ?

Comment: Please provide more details. What configuration are you referring to? You do not need to provide any mandatory resolution configuration.

Comment: When we write a sikuli script along with Selenium in a tool like Eclipse where image-recognition and comparison is required we save the screenshots of the images from which we want to compare (expected image) to the current image (actual image). And we provide the configuration of the system like 1920 x 1080 of the expected image and when before we run the script, system with configuration 1920 x 1080 has to be set. else image comparison will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are talking about SikuliX version 2.0.4 (latest stable).

There is never any need to specify screen dimensions, since they are evaluated automatically behind the scenes.

Might be, that I do not really understand, what you are talking about.

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: When we write a sikuli script along with Selenium in a tool like Eclipse where image-recognition and comparison is required we save the screenshots of the images from which we want to compare (expected image) to the current image (actual image). And we provide the configuration of the system like 1920 x 1080 of the expected image and when before we run the script, system with configuration 1920 x 1080 has to be set. else image comparison will fail.

Comment: Yes you are right @aish kapoor. We always need to provide system display resolution to 1920x1080 and size of text as 100% along with the browser zoom level as 100%. Otherwise scripts got failed.